# Invalid argument while writing a file

Tags: python

This code works :

```
f = open('Report\\StatusReport.csv', 'w', newline='')
```

I need to add timestamp to the filename, something similar to :

```
time_stamp = time.strftime("%d-%m-%y_%H:%M:%S")
f = open(f'Report\\StatusReport_{time_stamp}.csv', 'w', newline='')
```

which gives the error :

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:
```

Comment: Is there more to that error message…?

Comment: @deceze. It's windows, so probably not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:` colons are [not legal characters in windows file names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)

you should change this line

```
time_stamp = time.strftime("%d-%m-%y_%H:%M:%S")
```

to something line

```
time_stamp = time.strftime("%d-%m-%y_%H_%M_%S")
```